# As a Monk, will my skills be hindered by equipping a shield?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I'm currently playing a **Monk** in *Diablo 3*.

Recently, I found a shield, and noticed that I was able to equip it. I was under the impression that **Monks** used unarmed abilities and attacks. Equipping the shield gives me a nice defense boost, but I'm afraid it will hinder my damage, my ability to use skills, or both.

**Is using a shield on a Monk going to get me in a bind?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Monks do not suffer from equipping a shield, except for losing the ability to equip a 2nd fist weapon or wield a 2-handed monk staff.

To note, the majority of the monk skills involve the monk sheathing his weapons in the first place (fist-weapons excepted), so you do tend to wind up with your shield on your back a lot, but its a visual effect only, as you can still block attacks as normal.

Comment: Is this the same concept for wizards too?

Comment: @Foxtrot Yes. No class suffers a penalty from equipping anything.

Comment: Note: Dual-wielding weapons gives a 15% bonus to attack speed, which may be useful for a monk.

Comment: @Raven except for Demon Hunters who are locked out of several abilities if they font equip a bow.

Comment: Good point. But if you don't want to use a bow, why the heck are you playing a Demon Hunter?

Comment: 1h + shield seems to generate spirit significantly slower than dual wield.  It's often harder to keep up with healing while using a shield, even though you're taking a bit less damage.  Or else there were too many uncontrolled variables when I was comparing

Comment: @PeterCordes See AndrewKS' comment above - dual wielding gives an attack speed bonus.